# Actionability from Tensorboard's weight histograms?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, interpretation, tensorflow

There are a few questions across the site about how to interpret the weight histograms. I understand what the histogram is showing, but:

- What exactly does it mean when the weights in a given layer are within some range, in a nice gaussian distribution?
- What does it mean when the random initialization of the weights has a "wide" range that later gets more narrow after training and vice versa?
- Can one get an idea about convergence by looking at those histograms, like you would by plotting the weights of a convolutional layer as an image (especially within the first two or so layers)?

[image]
(Image borrowed from [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42315202/understanding-tensorboard-weight-histograms) for reference)